# multiple PassengerRoot?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger

how do you define multiple passengeroot - my gemsets are different so something like this:

```
PassengerRuby /Users/david/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rpgweb/ruby
PassengerRuby /Users/david/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.2-p290@eweds/ruby
```

And obviously that doens't work. I just put it in httpd.conf.

Is there any way so when it tries to load my localhost A, it iwll use the first gemset and localhost b it will use use the 2nd gemset for passenger?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excerpt from [Passenger documentation](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#PassengerRuby) for `PassengerRuby` directive:

> This option may only occur once, in the global server configuration.

You could use different gemsets per Rails application using .rvmrc. 
Check rvm documentation [Using RVM rubies with Passenger](http://rvm.io/integration/passenger) for details.